# Problem using vspace with tables

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing

- I have a problem using `\vspace` in **Latex**, because there is a wide vertical space between tables and paragraphs.
- I decided to use `\vspace{-4mm}` but it didn't have a big effect on the vertical spacing.
- so when I removed the parenthesis `\vspace -4mm`,I have got an Error `Missing number, treated as zero.`, but the result was perfect, how can I get the good result of removing the vertical space, and removing the error at same time ?

**EDIT: Minimal Working Example**
I added the link to the [MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xgxzsrcrcvhg) because it contains several attached files like `ieeeconference.cls` and `bibliography.bib`, and I'm not sure if the problem comes from any of them.

> **Good shape with error**
>
> [image: Good shape with Error]
>
> **Bad shape no errors**
>
> [image: Bad shape no error]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe. Without seeing the code it is impossible to tell you what went wrong. Generally, there should be no need for manual command such as `\vspace`.

Comment: Regarding: "Good shape with error": As soon as you get an error message, do not look at the output.  Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Since you used `ieeeconf` as your documentclass I assume you write a paper that you want to publish with them. I therefore suggest to not add changes to their default layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the use of the [`float`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) and the [`caption`](http://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) package. By creating a new caption style, a similar format to yours and a more efficient spacing should be achieved.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{custom_fl}{\MakeUppercase{#1} \MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #2}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{custom_f}{#1\par \textsc{#3}}
\captionsetup[table]{format=custom_f,labelformat=custom_fl}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]\\
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \caption{A table}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            Configuration &\\\hline
            Setting 1 & Values\\\hline
            Setting 2 & Value\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```